# How can i search in java file using javaParser?

Tags: java, javaparser

I have a problem that I changed the class name in java class using javaParser and now I want to change all references from the old name to the new name. 
For example, if I have a java class like this

```
class A{
 private static final Logger log4j = LoggerFactory.getLogger(A.class);
}
```

and I changed the name of A to B

```
class B{
     private static final Logger log4j = LoggerFactory.getLogger(A.class);
}
```

then I also want to scan all the files to change A to B using javaParser and I don't know how anybody here can help?

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor class name

This operation will automatically change all usages

[image]

Comment: What about not using IntelliJ Idea?

Comment: same for eclipse as well...                                   
http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_rename.htm

Comment: but i have a lot of projects and i want to change a lot of things like variale name not only class name and i want to make this automatically by JavaParser so refactor will not help me

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, 
for classes just right click on the class in the project explorer and select "Refactor->Rename". That it is is under the "Refactor" submenu. Shift + alt + r (Right click file ->refactor ->rename) when cursor is on class name.
For Variables
If you are on windows/ubuntu platform use alt+shift+R or on mac use command+option+r. It will refactor all the occurences where that variable is used.
To get the list of shortcuts available in eclipse, use ctrl+shift+L in windows/ubuntu and command+shift+l in mac.

Comment: but i have a lot of projects and i want to change a lot of things like variale name not only class name and i want to make this automatically by JavaParser so refactor will not help me